# How to migrate work items from one project to another project specific area path and create iterations using azure migration tools

Tags: json, powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-migration-tools, azure-migrate

How to migrate work items from one project to another project to a specific team and automate the creation of sprints which are existing in source project

Comment: Please refer [Bulk move work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/move-change-type?view=azure-devops) ,  [Azure DevOps Migration Tools](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/) , [Migrate data between Azure DevOps Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/extensions/migrate-integrate?view=azure-devops#migrate-data-between-azure-devops-projects) and [Define iteration paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-iteration-paths-sprints?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.